# Printing ArcMap layouts from ArcGIS Server Services (10.1+)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing, layouts

I've prepared a map with multiple data frames using ArcMap and setup my desired layout. I published the map onto the ArcGIS Server and setup a printing service which uses the custom layout of the published map.
However when i call for printing task from a jscript application all i see is the main map in one of the data frames correctly displayed and all. The other data frames appear and get the correct extent and grid etc but no map data shows.

in Jscript the printing parameters is passed in the following fashion:

```
parameters.map = bmap.map;
parameters.templates = templates;
printTask.execute(parameters, result);
```

Am i supposed to be adding some information about which dataframe in the map should be connected to which frame in the layout? Seems all that is happening is that the map is just sent as is to the dataframe which was set to active.

Any tips as to why this is happening? I can give some more info if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This [help article](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/create-web-apps/windows/printing-in-web-applications.htm) seems to answer your question.  Specifically this section:

"The PrintingTools service can print layouts that use multiple data frames. The service only replaces the map in the active data frame; however, if the data frames have some relationship between them, such as an extent rectangle, that relationship is honored by PrintingTools."

Comment: Thanks for the link, and i have indeed looked at the map and confirmed that it did respect the extent issue, its just that no map was displayed in the other frames except the active one. Thanks